# Generate a list of rows in a dataframe or matrix that contain matching elements

Tags: python-3.x

I have a set of values for a given user

```
UserA: 1 2 3
UserB: 2 3 
UserC: 3 4 
UserD: 1 
UserE: 5
```

I want to return a list of which users have at least one matching value, using python:

Output:

```
UserA: {UserD, UserB, UserC}, 
UserB:{UserA, UserC}, 
UserC:{UserA, UserB}, 
UserD: {UserA}, 
UserE:{NA}
```

Answer (score 0):

There probably is a better implementation, but this gives the expected output.

```py
users = {}
users["usera"] = [1, 2 ,3]
users["userb"] = [2 ,3]
users["userc"] = [3, 4]
users["userd"] = [1]
users["usere"] = [5]

result = {}

for key, val in users.items():
    result[key] = []
    for key2, val2 in users.items():
        for number in val2:
            if not key == key2 and key2 not in result[key]:
                if number in val:
                    result[key].append(key2)


print(result)
```

With the output being

```
{'usera': ['userb', 'userc', 'userd'], 'userb': ['usera', 'userc'], 'userc': ['usera', 'userb'], 'userd': ['usera'], 'usere': []}
```